# Is there a way to programmatically ensure geom_density gets to the x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found this on the Tidyverse Github:

https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3716

but I can't find the resolution of  yutannihilation's question.

For exploratory data analysis, I would like for the outline stroke to reach the x-axis as it does with base R, including facets with scales="free".

Is there a way to do this programmatically? The user may have multiple facets of data, on the same or different scales. Can I ensure the x-axis is wide enough to take the density to zero?

I have tried outline.type = "full" and "both" but neither seem to work.

The MRE shows the issue. The use case is within a Shiny app and can be `facet_wrap`-ed as well.

Thanks!

```
#R base
plot(density(diamonds$carat, adjust = 5))

#ggplot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
  geom_density(adjust = 5)
```

Comment: If you want to use function designed to more accurately handle densities with non-negative domains consider `logspline` in pkg:logspline or `logdensity` in pkg:logKDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward solution would be to calculate the density yourself and plot that:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(as.data.frame(density(diamonds$carat, adjust = 5)[1:2]), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with that is that there is a positive density for negative carat values. I think a better answer would be to suggest a different density function.

Comment: @IRTFM Presumably the OP's actual data doesn't have this problem, and they just want to know how to extend the density plot so it tails off sensibly outside the range of the data. Clearly not the best example data set, but I don't want to give an answer that only applies to this specific data set, since it may not be appropriate for their actual data.

Comment: I'm not sure where your presumption is supported. If there were negative values in the domain of the data the density graph would have extended there.

Comment: @IRTFM the point is that there are many data sets where it is reasonable to want a drop off in density outside the range of the data. For example, the plot `ggplot(data.frame(x = c(1000, 1000, 1000, 1200)), aes(x)) + geom_density()` cuts off abruptly at x = 1000, but there may be good reason for believing the density tails off below 1000 rather than having an absoloute floor value of 1000. Of course, you are correct that this is not the case in the `carat` data, but I would give enough credit to someone writing a data exploration app that they understand this.

Comment: It is a valid concern and I wrestled with the right way to go on this. While I know the danger, the users of the app may not. I decided in the end to put a checkbox in the app. In most use cases where they are exploring data (real world industrial data) I would think there is a good chance that extending the density beyond the data would make sense. But as with the caret data, in some cases you want it to stop with the data. I am also adding a rug under the density plot to help them visualize the points that are generating the density. Thanks @AllanCameron

Comment: I had to mess with the data to get facets working, but this pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!